# OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability with latest openssl 1.1.0c

Tags: centos, security, openssl

I have a test server running Centos 6.8 and can't overcome this message when running a SSL Labs test: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=biduno.com&latest

> This server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability
>   (CVE-2016-2107) and insecure. Grade set to F. I believe it's to do
>   with open openssl and I have the latest version OpenSSL 1.1.0c 10 Nov
>   2016.

Could it be to do with my Ciphers?

> SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 SSLCipherSuite
>   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:+TLSv1.1:+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!ADH:!EDH:!AESGCM
>   SSLHonorCipherOrder on

Comment: Welcome to U&L what is the output of `rpm -q --changelog openssl | egrep -i "(CVE-2016-2107)"` ?

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for responding :) 

# rpm -q --changelog openssl | egrep -i "(CVE-2016-2107)"
- fix CVE-2016-2107 - padding oracle in stitched AES-NI CBC-MAC
- fix CVE-2016-2107 - padding oracle in stitched AES-NI CBC-MAC

Comment: `- fix CVE-2016-2107 - padding oracle in stitched AES-NI CBC-MAC`
`- fix CVE-2016-2107 - padding oracle in stitched AES-NI CBC-MAC`

Comment: please check for the vulnerability here https://filippo.io/CVE-2016-2107/ what is the result ?

Comment: I get `biduno.com IS VULNERABLE.`

Comment: After upgrading to the latest openssl I rebooted the server if that helps.

Comment: This is quite odd. When I look at phpinfo it says I'm using the old openssl rather than the new one that sows on ssh > openssl version

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... Have you run `sudo yum update` within the last 6 months or so?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to tune protocols, ciphers and some other settings to suit your taste. You are also mixing protocols and cipher suites, which probably isn't good.

Here's the basic SSL/TLS configuration for [www.cryptopp.com](http://www.cryptopp.com/), which is an open source project I help with. It runs on a CentOS 7 VM, and scores a "A" with the Qualsys tests. None of us are Apache experts, so take the configuration at face value. We do enough so users don't experience problems, but not much more.

Usually you want something like "TLS 1.0 and above" (`SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2`) and "Modern cipher suites" (`SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4`). The `!kRSA` means "no RSA key transport", which effectively leaves Diffie-Hellman and forward secrecy.

The configuration also sets the STS header (`Strict-Transport-Security`).

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf | grep -v '#'
Listen 443 https

SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName www.cryptopp.com:443
ServerAlias *.cryptopp.com cryptopp.com

ErrorLog logs/error_log
TransferLog logs/access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cryptopp-com.chain.pem

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/cryptopp-com.key.pem

SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cryptopp-com.chain.pem

SSLVerifyClient none

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552001; includeSubdomains;"

</VirtualHost>
```

---

I'm also guessing you are *not* using OpenSSL 1.1.0. Rather, you are probably using an older FIPS version. Here's from the same CetOS 7 VM:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Maintainers backport patches, so about all you know is (1) you started somewhere around 1.0.1e, (2) you don't really know what you have at the moment, and (3) you have a Frekenstein-like contraption that's been pieced together.